# Unable to configure Facebook app for Facebook App Center - App details page

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-app-center

I have an iOS app that uses iOS SDK and has been approved by Facebook for basic info + date of birth + location city

I want to list it on the App Center and trying to submit another application with the following permission:

> App Details You only need to submit App Details when you want your app
>   to be listed in App Center. Your app is automatically searchable on
>   Facebook once you fill out App Details and make your app public.

However, I am getting an error that the App Details is not complete, but upon checking that page it does look complete to me (image attached)

Any idea about what is still missing and how to complete it? Thanks a lot

[image]

I can confirm that all non-optional picture fields have been filled in, if not apparent from this image attached

Also to confirm, the `App Center Listed Platforms` could not be configured as both the buttons are inactive

[image]

Comment: For iOS you need to use Single Sign on to be allowed to list that platform in App Center. You also need to have inputted iphone store id or ipad store id in the Basic settings

Comment: same issue is happening with me. my application is still development phase.Please also tell me how can enable it for iOS-iPhone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, under `App Center Listed Platforms` you have both options set to `no`.  One needs to say `yes`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried putting those options to YES, however, they are inactive. Please see the revised original post, where I have put a snap of this case as well.

Comment: Have you tried clicking `configure app center permissions`?  What does it show there?  Or at the very top `click here to update your integration`?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. In `Settings` under `iOS` section, `Single Sign On` option should say `YES`.

Answer (score 4):

You should fill in `iPhone store ID` in `Settings`, and then you can enable the switch in `App Center Listed Platforms`

Comment: Note that if your app is not yet approved by Apple, you can fill any live iPhone store ID as long as you update it when your app goes live.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This is the answer i got from facebook support:

> Facebook Team
>
> Hi Geert,
>   Thanks for reaching out.
>
> Unfortunately games only available on either iOS or Android, and not on web, are not eligible for App Center.
>
> You can read more details about the requirements for eligibility at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/listing/.
>
> Please let us know if you have more questions.
>
> All the best,

But for the greyed-out buttons, it turns out

```
 Settings -> basic -> iOS -> Single Sign = On
```

enables

```
 App Center -> Details -> App Center Listed Platforms -> iOS - iPhone
```

And

```
 Settings -> basic -> Android -> Single Sign = On
```

enables

```
 App Center -> Details -> App Center Listed Platforms -> Android
```